# Openlayer clustering with different color of image

Tags: colors, openlayers, openlayers-3, layer, markerclusterer

So basically I have several hundred of features containing a geom. I want the map to cluster different color of points.

This is the features and color:

```
//so both features and color contain several hundred of value
features.push(new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([random_x, random_y])));
color.push(random_color)
```

Then with each feature[i], it should display in the map with color[i]. 
This is the code that is currently working now which display with one color only, how should I change to let each point display its own color and it can still remain the clustering function? Please help.

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: features
});

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 40,
    source: source
});

var styleCache = {};
var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
    name: 'clusterlayer',
    source: clusterSource,
    style: function(feature) {
        var size = feature.get('features').length;
        var style = styleCache[size];
        if (!style) {
            style = [new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 10,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#000000'
                    })
                }),

                text: new ol.style.Text({
                    font: 'bolder',
                    text: size.toString(),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#000000',
                    })
                })
            })];
            styleCache[size] = style;
        }
        return style;
    }
});
this.state.map.addLayer(clusters);
```

For more advance work, how should I do to  say like a red and blue circle point, when clustering, it will show up a thing like green circle, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this example http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/map/map.clustering.html.

The circle is cut according to what it contains to reflect the colors.